# ValueError: could not convert string to float: empty string in variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have a value error, how i can fix it, when my script crash variable get empty string, i try to write script for ping, and get response time from server, if time more than 100 i print BAD, if low 100 i print good, but somewhere i get empty string, from ping output, and i dont know how to resolve this problem, if you know how to improve my code, im glad to see your comments, im just training in python. thank you in advance.

```
import subprocess
import time
import os
import re


def main():
    host_list = ['google.com', 'facebook.com', 'gmail.com', 'vk.com', '114.141.102.124', '192.168.255.129', '8.8.8.8']
    while True:
        for item in host_list:
            command = "ping " + item + " -c 1"
            ping = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
            ping_out = ping.communicate()[0]
            pattern_ping_time = r'(time=\d{0,4}.\d{0,2})'
            pattern_connection_lost = r'(100% packet loss)'
            time_r = re.findall(pattern_ping_time, ping_out)
            conn_lost = re.findall(pattern_connection_lost, ping_out)
            time_r_s = ''.join(time_r)
            time_r_s_form = time_r_s.strip('time=')
            print(time_r_s_form)
            time_r_s_form_float = float(time_r_s_form)
            print(time_r_s_form_float)
            if time_r_s_form_float > 100.0:
                print(item + "  " + '\x1b[0;30;41m' + "bad" + '\x1b[0m')
            elif time_r_s_form_float < 100.0:
                print(item + "  " + '\x1b[6;30;42m' + "good" + '\x1b[0m')
            elif conn_lost:
                print(item + "  " + '\x1b[0;30;41m' + "connection lost" + '\x1b[0m')
            else:
                print("no data")
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system('clear')


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

out_put :

```
47.2
47.2
google.com  good
39.5
39.5
facebook.com  good
45.5
45.5
gmail.com  good
72.3
72.3
vk.com  good

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 63, in <module>
    main()
  File "script.py", line 22, in main
    time_r_s_form_float = float(time_r_s_form)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: Try adding `print(repr(ping_out))` to see why the regex can't find anything at `114.141.102.124`.

Comment: 'PING 114.141.102.124 (114.141.102.124) 56(84) bytes of data.\n\n--- 114.141.102.124 ping statistics ---\n1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms\n\n'

Comment: Good. Now figure out what you want your program to do if that happens. Maybe display an error message?

Comment: can you text me what is "repr"?

Comment: Google is your friend.

Comment: pattern_ping_time = r'(time=\d{0,4}.\d{0,2})'
            pattern_connection_lost = r'(100% packet loss)'
            if re.findall(pattern_connection_lost, ping_out):
                print(item + "  " + '\x1b[0;30;41m' + "connection lost" + '\x1b[0m')
            elif re.findall(pattern_ping_time, ping_out):
                 how i can get variable from re, here?

Comment: @Aran-Fey yeah why not display error message? Therefore Displaying a error message if an error happens isn’t how error handling works.isn’t it?

Comment: @pajarnas It depends on the error. Displaying an error message *can* be a form of error handling.

Comment: id do something like this:             elif re.findall(pattern_ping_time, ping_out):
                response_time = re.findall(pattern_ping_time, ping_out)
                time_r_s = ''.join(response_time)

Comment: @Aran-Fey But If you  regarding 0 as a flag to print error messages,it’s a good form of displaying error messages And in your opinion a form of error handling.

Comment: in this case, when i need to get 0 or 1, i need to call subprocess.call, i use need subprocess.Popen

Comment: @pajarnas Setting the variable to 0 is a completely pointless step in that process.